# Clifton StrengthsFinder

Tags: psychology, diagnostic-test

A friend of mine is trying to convince me to go take a Clifton StrengthsFinder test and participate in related seminars. I have trouble inding any information about the test that does not come from the organization that owns it/ people working for it.

My question is: **do these tests provide any actually useful information?**

(I wanted to also ask a question if there is any point in attending the seminars, but I can see this question was already answered  here [Do Personal Development Seminars bring real long-term benefits?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/do-personal-development-seminars-bring-real-long-term-benefits)

Comment: This is missing a claim.  We provide citations either confirming or disputing a claim.  If you want to ask here, you should find some place where the Clifton people assert something and ask about that.  Otherwise, this is in danger of being marked off-topic.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you hear or read. This question doesn't appear to have any doubtful claims to investigate. Please edit it to reference a notable claim and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).